# Getting class error while using Keras.layers.Add()

Tags: merge, keras, addition, layer

I am trying to add two layers each of size  `(None, 24, 24, 8)` but getting the class error as below:

Code:

```
x = add([layers[i-1],layers[i-9]])
```

or

```
x = Add()([layers[i-1],layers[i-9]])
```

Error:

```
/keras_222/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 285, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
ValueError: Layer add_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. **Received type: <class** 'keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f04e4085850>, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f050013cd10>]. All inputs to the **layer should be tensors**.
```

Please advise how to move forward. I also tried putting axis=1 or axis=-1 but it didn't work.

```
x = Add()([layers[i-1],layers[i-9]],axis=1)
```

or

```
x = Add()([layers[i-1],layers[i-9]], axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing layers instead of tensors to your `Add()` layer. I suppose you have an `Input()` layer somewhere in your code. You need to pass this input through your other layers. Your code should instead look something like this:

```
input = Input(shape)
# pass input through other intermediate layers first if needed

output_1 = layers[i-1](input)
output_2 = layers[i-9](input)

x = Add()([output_1, output_2])
```

Comment: Thanks! I forget to realize that.